# Firebase getting data in letter order

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I sort the following data in letter order? So "deviceRooms1, deviceRooms2, deviceRooms3, ..." I want the data sorted.

[image: Firebase Data]

```
@objc func fetchRooms()
        {
     let ref = Database.database().reference().child("0").child("Rooms")

            ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                //let value: NSDictionary = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
                let dic = snapshot.value as! [String:String]
                self.tableRowss = Array(dic.values)
                self.myTableView.reloadData()

            })

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
let dic = snapshot.value as! [String:String]
let sortedKeys = Array(dic.keys).sorted(by:<)
self.tableRowss = sortedKeys.map { dic[$0]! }
self.myTableView.reloadData()
```